Can we solve this using Mean Value Theorem's (Lagrange/Cauchy/Intermediate) or Rolle's Theorem?
I came across the following question:-

For every pair of continuous function $f,g:[0, 1] \to \mathbb R \text{ such that } \max \{f(x): x \in [0,1] \}= \max \{g(x): x\in [0,1]\}$, the correct statement(s) is (are):


A.$[f(c)]^2+3f(c)$=$[g(c)]^2+3g(c)$ for some $c \in [0, 1]$
B.$[f(c)]^2+f(c)$=$[g(c)]^2+3g(c)$ for some $c \in [0, 1]$
C.$[f(c)]^2+3f(c)$=$[g(c)]^2+g(c)$ for some $c \in [0, 1]$
D.$[f(c)]^2$ = $[g(c)]^2$ for some $c \in [0, 1]$

And almost on all the sites I tried finding out the solution , I  was only able to see one method being used everywhere.
But I believe that there must be some method to solve this question by using either of the mean value theorems or the Rolle's Theorem and I am also able to see a hint from the options ("for some $c \in [0,1]$"). Can anyone just pass me a hint if this is possible?

As both, Rolle's Theorem and the MVT (a generalization of Rolle's Theorem) require some differentiability assumption on the interior, i don't think they are directly applicable.

Thanks a lot!! @epartow

$f-g$ must be $0$ at some point $c$, otherwise (by the intermediate value theorem) it would be either always $>0$ or always $<0$, which would contradict the hypothesis $\max(f)=\max(g)$. Indeed, if for instance $g<f$ on $[0,1]$ then $\max(g)=g(x_0)<f(x_0)\le\max(f)$.
Therefore, A and D are correct.
B and C are not: a counterexample is $f=g=1$.
N.B. As commented by @epartow, the other theorems you mentionned cannot be used.
